# Wait until send_keys has finished to click a button (with Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning Selenium and trying to automate a task.
The task consists of uploading a zip file from the typical input file and clicking on the upload button. I've gotten it to work, but sometimes it fails because the upload button is pressed before send_keys has finished and the page shows a dialog saying there is nothing to upload.

This is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://localhost:8008/management/#/welcome')
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
EC.url_matches('http://localhost:8008/management/#/welcome'))
driver.get('http://localhost:8008/management/#/configuration-engines')
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.url_matches('http://localhost:8008/management/#/configuration-engines'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'userfile'))).send_keys(file_path)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'upload_and_install')))
button = driver.find_element_by_id('upload_and_install').click()
```

This is the HTML code of the input (with or without a file, it does not change. They do not have a value to check if it has changed):

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="userfile" dir="ltr">
```

The solution that I have found is to simply do a time.sleep(5), but I would like to know if there is a more "clean" way.

Comment: You need to click on Upload a file button first then can use .send_keys right ?

Comment: No, with send_keys() I add the file to the input and it works fine, the problem is that the following instruction (click on the button and upload the file) is executed before send_keys() has finished doing its job (put the file in the input).

Comment: What is size of file ?

Comment: Between 900MB and 1.1GB

Comment: I see. You would have to depend on time.sleep(5 or 10 sec) for more stability. Having said that Do you see any progress bar on the UI when it's uploading a file ?

Comment: No, the screen just goes dark and a wheel comes out spinning. I'll leave it with the time.sleep(), I just wanted to know if there was some "cleaner" way to do it, with WebDriverWait or something like that.

Comment: yes there is, if you see the spinning wheel, Can you give me HTML of wheel  which spins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by OP, that there is a Wheel spinning, I would suggest you to use `ExplicitWait - invisibility_of_element`

**Sample code :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "Wheel spining xpath")))
```

This line will wait for the invisibility of the provided xpath.